# Find the locus of the complex number satisfying the following condition?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Find the locus of a complex number z satisfying $|z^2+z+1|=1$. Also desribe the locus.

This is how I proceed
$$Since \enspace|z^2+z+1|=1$$
I can proceed as follows:
$$ let\enspace z^2+z+1=e^{i\theta}$$
*This is where I got stuck.I have no idea how to proceed further. I tried solving for z using the quadratic equation formula but every time I tried I got messed up.*
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Represent $z=x+iy$, ${\rm Re}(z^2+z+1)=x^2-y^2+x+1=\cos\theta$, ${\rm Im}(z^2+z+1)=2xy+y=\sin\theta$, $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$, $(x^2-y^2+x+1)^2+(2xy+y)^2=1$. It is 4-th order curve, closed, oval-like, symmetric of $x=-1/2$ and $y=0$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Thanks a lot!